# Update Queue emailaddress

Tags: apex, query, queue

I have to update an email address from a Queue via Apex, but I can't seem to get it right.

I have tried this, but it only returns null values..

```
for ( QueueSobject q : [SELECT Id, Queue.Name, Queue.Email FROM QueueSobject WHERE SobjectType='Case']){
system.debug('Name: '+q.Queue.Name+' -> '+q.Queue.Email);}
```

Anyone?

Comment: It is not the emailaddress of the queue members that I need to update but the email address of the queue itself (for sending notifications)

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer to my question. You need to use the "Group" Object instead of QueueSobject.

```
Group[] grps = [SELECT Id, Name, Email FROM Group WHERE Type = 'Queue' AND Email != ''];
for (Group grp : grps) {
    grp.Email = null;
}
```